# capture Python script output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written very small script and try to capture output of the script. I have written multiple time similar way but never had issue. Could I have input. I think I am doing very silly mistake

```
numpy_temp = """
import numpy
import sys
a, b, c = numpy.polyfit(%s,%s, 2)
print a, b, c""" %(x, y)
fp_numpy = open("numpy_temp.py", "w")
fp_numpy.write(numpy_temp)
cmd = "/remote/Python-2.7.2/bin/python numpy_temp.py "
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
out, err = proc.communicate()
print "out", out
```

Comment: Maybe you are actually getting stderr response.  Try `print out, err` and see if you have anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never actually closing `fp_numpy`, so the script can be empty or incomplete at the time you try to run it.

It isn't *guaranteed* to be empty, but it's very *likely*. When I try this on two different *nix computers with 7 different versions of Python, it's empty every time… (The fact that, after your script finishes, the file gets closed, and therefore flushed, makes the problem harder to debug.)

The best way to fix this is to use a `with` statement, so it's impossible to forget to close the file:

```
with open("numpy_temp.py", "w") as fp_numpy:
    fp_numpy.write(numpy_temp)
```

---

But beyond that, you've got another problem. If the generated script raises an exception, it will print nothing to stdout, and will dump a traceback to stderr, which you will read and ignore. It's very hard to debug problems when you're ignoring the errors… I don't know what you're passing for `x` and `y`, but if you're, say, passing a `numpy.array` instead of a string that evaluates to one, you could easily get an exception and never see it. Either send stderr to stdout, or `print "err", err` at the end.

And finally, you really shouldn't be using a command string and `shell=True` here, because you end up with an extra level of indirection for no good reason, which can *also* make things harder to debug. Just do this:

```
cmd = ["/remote/Python-2.7.2/bin/python", "numpy_temp.py"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Indeed, the file is not closed, and is subsequently empty.

Answer (score 0):

use `print out` not `print "out"`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this method

see.py

```
for line in range(6):
    print line
```

me@pubx:~$ python see.py > all

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you'd want to write a script to capture the output of a script (maybe you have a good reason). this sort of task is much easier using the shell.

Create your `numpy_temp.py` and then pipe it's output to a file.

```
/remote/Python-2.7.2/bin/python numpy_temp.py > output.txt
```

To append the data to an existing file use

```
/remote/Python-2.7.2/bin/python numpy_temp.py >> output.txt
```